# Retrofit returns just success/failure response ... no model .. how to make the retrofit request

Tags: android, retrofit2

**What I am able to do**:

- Make retrofit network request and get a successful response
- Here I am parsing to model

**What I am trying to achieve**:

- If my Request just a subcell and failure response, How can I parse
  the data side I don't have a model server returns
- How to modify my code below

**Example:**

```
 public void GetHash() {

        prepareBody();

        Call<CheckSumHash> posts = retrofit.create(Restapi.class).getCheckSum(prepareHeaders(),prepareBody());

        mAlert = new SweetAlert(activity);
        mAlert.startProgress();

        //Enque the call
        posts.enqueue(new Callback<CheckSumHash>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CheckSumHash> call, Response<CheckSumHash> response) {
                mAlert.stopProgress();
                CheckSumHash mFacetData = response.body();

                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                String json = gson.toJson(mFacetData);// obj is your object
                Map<String,String> result = new Gson().fromJson(json, Map.class);


                EventBus.getDefault().post(new BusHashSumResponse(result));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CheckSumHash> call, Throwable error) {
                mAlert.stopProgress();
                //Set the error to the textview
                if(error instanceof SocketTimeoutException){
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new ConnectionTimeout(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.str_socket_timeout)));
                }else if(error instanceof IOException){
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new NoConnectivity(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.str_no_connectivity)));
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the code for ``CheckSumHash`` and are you sure the json is returned with all the data?

Comment: If I am returned just 200 on success response ..... What to add in place of `CheckSumHash` .... should i need to add `Void` or something else

Comment: You can get a 200 response and no body... Not sure how retrofit handles this. I wanted to see an example of your json and the code for ``CheckSumHash`` because they need to match.

Comment: I Have not posted the `CheckSumHash` Because its a working sample and posted code works if there response is `Checksumhash`. Now suppose instead of it i get just 200 response ... I am trying to solve it.